# Text overlaping problem using itext for generating a pdf

Tags: java, itext

hi everyone
     i have a header text(ARTIST Biography(Continue)) in my pdf file generated by using itext(Java).where 'ARTIST' and '(Continue)' are static text 'Biography' is a dynamic text it will be varied with respect to the content fetched from xml.My problem is while the dynamic text length is too long it will overlap the '(continue)' text.How can i set the dynamic text length with respect to the nearest static text'(Continue)'.please reply
Thanks in advance

My code for displaying the header text is (ARTIST Biography(Continue)) written bellow

```
PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
        BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
        cb.setFontAndSize(bf, 18);
        cb.beginText();
        cb.setColorFill(Color.BLACK);
        cb.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT,"ARTIST", document.left(), document.top() + 20  , 0);
        cb.resetRGBColorFill();
        cb.endText();
        cb.beginText();
        cb.setColorFill(Color.RED);
        cb.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, strBiography, document.left() + 70, document.top() + 20, 0);
        cb.resetRGBColorFill();
        cb.endText();
        cb.beginText();
        cb.setColorFill(Color.BLACK);
        cb.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT,"(Continue)", document.left()+90, document.top() + 20  , 0);
        cb.resetRGBColorFill();
        cb.endText();
        cb.stroke();
```

Comment: Please provide a code sample of what you are doing. We need more context before being able to answer your question. (And while doing that, can you edit your question layout to something  more readable?)

Comment: _How can i set the cell width occupying the dynamic text_ Are you talking about cells in a PdfPTable? or ...

Comment: please review the edited question and code u had asked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create Chunk with the right font and content of strBiography and on the Chunk call [getWidthPoint](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/Chunk.html#getWidthPoint%28%29) to now it's size in points, you'll have about the length of your strBiography when added to the doc and can calculate the position of "(Continue)"